# Spouse relationship in a Drupal view

Tags: drupal-views

I currently have a Drupal View Displaying the current user and his/her spouse (AKA Drupal User and CiviCRM Contact B)
For some reason it will only Display the Drupal User and spouse if the spousal relationship was created from the Drupal User's CiviCRM contact profile. 
If the spousal relationship was created from Contact B's CiviCRM profile, then nothing is displayed. 
Is there a way to get this working regardless where the relationship was added?

[image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the relationship from the contact ID B?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I see this has been down voted but it does sound like you need to add a second pair of Relationships to cover the situation of your user being 'contact B'.

Answer (score -1):

Are the relationships permissioned? Your users probably can only see their spouses if it's a permissioned relationship, and perhaps when the relationship is bring created the second way it isn't being created in such a way that it is permissioned.

Comment: Views doesn't 'know' about permissioned relationships, so while this is something to consider in CiviCRM and webforms it doesn't (yet) affect Views.

Comment: Ah, good to know :) Sorry then, that's not the answer.

Comment: That is too bad. I have a situation where it would be VERY helpful.

Comment: The company I worked for has patched this now. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20319